# PHP:open and read directory, which contains pdf files

Tags: php, pdf

Am creating pdf files with `TCPDF`.Every single user gets a different folder.

This is a path name: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bandymas/pdfDocuments/'.$_SESSION["userSession"]`.There are no problem with file creation.

Now i need to see a list of created files and make them available for open.

The problem is, my page is crashing and I can't see the list.

```
 $dir='/'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bandymas/pdfDocuments/'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'/';


if(is_dir($dir)){

  if($dh=opendir($dir)){

echo "My documents list:";
    while(($fileName=readdir($dir)) !==false){

  echo "<a href=".$fileName."> view</a>","\n";

}
close($dh);
}
}
```

Comment: What does "my page is crashing" actually mean? Please be _specific_. What exactly do you see? What entry do you get in your http servers error log file?

Comment: I see a blank page, and the browser loads the page all the time, after some time, my browser crashes and closes.There are only 5 files in my directory.This script is used from http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

Comment: _Your browser crashes_? In that case you have a very serious issue with your local system or that browser software, but that certainly has nothing to do with that php script.

Comment: About that page you cited where you took that snippet from.... I checked, that page does _not_ contain that error your script contains, so you must have altered it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that line: `while(($fileName=readdir($dir)) !==false)`

A simple look into the [php documentation of that function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php) points out the reason why things fail:

`string readdir ([ resource $dir_handle ] )` requries a *directory handle* as argument, not a file system path. So the line *should* be: `while(($fileName=readdir($dh)) !==false)`. `$dh` is the variable holding your directory handle you got returned a few lines above when opening the folder.

This is a very common and typical issues with scripts getting implemented. We all make such mistakes. Nothing to worry about. But what you should learn from this is: *monitor your http servers error log file.* Such issues are pointed out in there, you can actually *read* in there what issue you are dealing with and typically also in which precise line in what file that issue occurs. *You cannot seriously develop php without monitoring that error log file*.

Comment: Now I have a list, but there are issues with the file opening, maybe the `fileName` is bad

Comment: Glad to hear that you made progress! But I am afraid I cannot help with that, since you did not post any information about those file names. However one question: what entries do you see in your http servers error log file now?

Answer (score 0):

Use Code Below Working Just Fine.

```
 $dir='/'.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bandymas/pdfDocuments/'.$_SESSION['userSession'].'/';

if (is_dir($dir)){

if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
}
```

You used `close($dh)` instead of `closedir($dh)`